# Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios, vite

This is the first time I created a react app using Vite and deployed it to Firebase, when trying to view it online I keep getting the above-mentioned error
I use `import axios from 'axios'` to import Axios into all my components

**These are my files**

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

.firebaserc

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "fir-auth-b0c11"
  }
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["axios"],
    },
  },
});
```

I am lost, I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the RollupError

```
npm install --save-dev @rollup/plugin-inject
```

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
const inject = require('@rollup/plugin-inject');

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [inject({
        readable: ['readable', 'Readable'] // Modify this line based on your specific needs
      })],
      external: ["axios"],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I tried those steps and got the error `RollupError: "Readable" is not exported by "__vite-browser-external"`

Comment: updated for rolluperror,if this  doesn't work ,let me know ,we can try to solve it other way.

Comment: try updating the vite and its plugins if this doesnot work
npm install vite @vitejs/plugin-react

Comment: after making crucial changes if you expect your changes to work and they still does not always try to restart server and try reloading or open in incognito